# WCF Data Service not exposing service operations

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, odata

I am making some POC using the Open Data Protocol (OData). My objective is to expose some custom methods as service operations along with entities but they are not displayed while being reachable.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class WcfDataService2 : DataService<MyDataSourceProvider>
    {
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyProducts", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MySuppliers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyLondonSuppliers", EntitySetRights.AllRead);

            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("GetSuppliersByCity", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("LondonSuppliers", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("UpdateProductName", ServiceOperationRights.All);

            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<Supplier> GetSuppliersByCity(string city)
        {
            return DataRepository.Suppliers.Where(s => s.Town.ToLower().Contains(city.ToLower())).AsQueryable();
        }

        [WebGet]
        public IQueryable<Supplier> LondonSuppliers()
        {
            return DataRepository.Suppliers.Where(s => s.County == "London").AsQueryable();
        }

        [WebGet]
        public string UpdateProductName(int ID, string Name)
        {
            DataRepository.Products.First(p => p.ProductID == ID).Name = Name;
            return "ok";
        }
    }
}
```

When I query the service at `http://localhost:51696/WcfDataService2.svc/`, all I see are the entities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<service xml:base="http://localhost:51696/WcfDataService2.svc/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
  <workspace>
    <atom:title>Default</atom:title>
    <collection href="MyProducts">
      <atom:title>MyProducts</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="MySuppliers">
      <atom:title>MySuppliers</atom:title>
    </collection>
    <collection href="MyLondonSuppliers">
      <atom:title>MyLondonSuppliers</atom:title>
    </collection>
  </workspace>
</service>
```

No trace of the methods:

- GetSuppliersByCity
- LondonSuppliers
- UpdateProductName

Am I missing something?

By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0.

Comment: Mark the operation as [OperationContract] and the service as [ServiceContract]? You should aways declare a Interface for your services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for me, it seems that OData V2 has some limitations including the ability to expose the service operations:

> Service operations (which is what the WebGet method is called) are not exposed in the service document (that's the response to the request to the root of the server). Only entity sets are exposed there.

I found this answer on some [Microsoft Forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0c79f0c8-c87e-442c-9c75-36d10d958d6a/webget-method-in-wcf-data-service-is-not-showing?forum=adodotnetdataservices%20Microsoft%20Forum%20thread).

Answer (score 0):

Try set the MaxProtocolVersion to V3

```
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
```

Comment: I can't : .NET 4.0 does not embed V3 or V4. And I do not have the rights to install any thing else requiring admin rights such as .NET 4.5 or VS2013...